# How to preserve pointers between multiple method calls in C

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, recursion, char

I'm writing a parser for propositional logic (doesn't matter what that is, main point is I'm parsing a simple language) and initially started out with functions of the following form:

```
int formula() {
    int store = step;
    if(compound())
        return TRUE;
    else {
        if(atom())
            return TRUE;
        else if(negation() && formula())
            return TRUE;
        else {
            step = store;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

int compound() {
    int store = step;
    if(open() && formula() && binary_operator() && formula() && close())
        return TRUE;
    else {
        step = store;
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The functions above not mentioned are base cases - these are the important parts. Formulas can have sub-formulas, and these sub-formulas in turn can be compound formulas, which contain sub-formulas, and so on.

Instead of ints though, I'm trying to return char sequences of 1s and 0s (true and false). If you return a sequence, it means that the input can generate a sequence (it must be valid). Otherwise, return null.

The issue is that every time I've tried the pointers keep getting lost - I understand this is to do with the stack(?) and the pointer sort of 'dies' when the function returns whatever. I've not tried arrays because I have been told that arrays work best statically, whereas the size of these arrays would be dynamic (size is determined by number of variables, which is only found at runtime).

Is there any way this approach can be done? I can't malloc anything because I won't be able to free it - the sequence of 1s and 0s needs to be returned before I'd be able to free it. Maybe pass structs with a sequence field, although I'm not sure if that suffers from the same issue.

Any help much appreciated. This is a program using C99. Any advice on clarifications welcome!

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_! And use prototype function declarators. The old-style ones are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me! I've just started learning C after having been weaned on Java!

Comment: Why can't you free the `malloc`ed memory later when the work is done. It is not a necessity to free it in the same function.

Comment: "Besides, an array is still a pointer once it's used." No, it is still an **array**. If it was a pointer, it would be called "pointer". If you have problems with the C concepts, you should read a C book before starting a project at this level.

Comment: Haris - the main concern is being able to find the memory that I malloc'ed after the whole process is done. I'm not sure that I could find all the malloc'ed sequences. If there was a way then perhaps that would work.

Comment: @Olaf I was told that an array is effectively a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @DanielSoutar go back to whever told you that and hit them with something.  Something pointy would be best.

Comment: I agree with @MartinJames. Get your money back from whoever told you. I would be more careful recommending violence, though - the recommendation is problematic here ...

Comment: I just looked up the difference, so let me try again - is an array a constant pointer with an unchangeable address? Or is that still wrong?

Comment: Fine. An array is just a collection of elements (of the same type) that are allocated consecutively in memory. Back to the original question - is there any way I can use char pointers in the code above instead of TRUE/FALSE or not?

Comment: The guys here are being a bit pedantic. While an array is just a consecutive sequence of elements, the value of the variable the array is bound to will often implicitly convert into a pointer type in your code. That is why `char string[] = "abc"; printf("%s\n", string);` works for example.

Comment: Thanks for that Kurt - much more informative and illuminating! Does that have any implications for my question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely following what you want to do, but there is not a clear reason why you couldn't use malloc. The pointer returned by malloc can be freed by another function later. Consider the following valid code:

```
char* foo(size_t* length)
{
    *length = 3;
    char* seq = malloc(*length);
    seq[0] = 1;
    seq[1] = 0;
    seq[2] = 1;
    return seq;
}

int main()
{
    size_t length;
    char* seq = foo(&length);
    /* use seq */
    free(seq);
}
```

You can also do it without `malloc` if you know an upper bound for your sequence. By passing a pointer to space you allocated on the stack from `main()`, you won't lose the data when the function exits:

```
void foo(char* seq, size_t total_size, size_t* used_size)
{
    *used_size = 3;
    seq[0] = 1;
    seq[1] = 0;
    seq[2] = 1;
}

int main()
{
    size_t used_size;
    char seq[100];
    foo(seq, sizeof(seq), &used_size);
    /* use seq */
}
```

Comment: I apologize. The original code had a bunch of problems due to copy/paste error. I believe they have all been fixed now.